# Can aspirin revive a flat car battery?

Tags: road-vehicles, battery

I just read [this article on The Reader's Digest](http://www.rd.com/home/5-car-battery-tips-and-tricks/) which writes to say

> If you get behind the wheel only to discover that your car’s battery
>   has given up the ghost — and there’s no one around to give you a jump
>   — you may be able to get your vehicle started by dropping two aspirin
>   tablets into the battery itself. The aspirin’s acetylsalicylic acid
>   will combine with the battery’s sulfuric acid to produce one last
>   charge. Just be sure to drive to your nearest service station.

Does this technique work to revive a flat car battery enough for one more start?

Comment: It doesn't even make sense--there are six cells, not two.  Even if an aspirin could revive a flat cell you need all six to start the car.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Potentially quibbling - it could be construed to mean 2-aspirin per cell.

Comment: It just says "the battery". This is an article for general consumption, it makes no sense to read it except for as a layperson would. Not that it matters, since a weak organic acid would do nothing to help a strong inorganic acid to do anything it wasn't already able.

Comment: IF the battery were just a tiny bit low on acid, chucking in something acidic might help just enough to give you a spark from your spark plug. But it'd be a very marginal thing indeed. And it's not just aspirine that'd do, but anything acidic.

Comment: @Nij: A weak organic acid & strong inorganic acid may together constitute a superacid.... For instance (if one is to believe the world-wide-web as a source) Acetic acid and Sulphuric acid.

Comment: Hmmm, most car batteries today are sealed, so you can't pour anything into the cells...

Comment: Reader's Digest turned into Buzzfeed so gradually, I didn't even notice.